# Manipulating data before rendering in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Coming with an Angular background to React, I can't wrap my head around on how to manipulate and restructure data before rendering it.
Let's say I pass this object from parent component to child:

```
{
    "_id": "5c716c53591610007f6d44ef",
    "model": {
        "_id": "5c7166eb591610007f6d44d4",
        "name": "E 300"
    },
    "serie": {
        "_id": "5c716ba0591610007f6d44e2",
        "name": "E-Class"
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5c716c60591610007f6d44f2",
    "model": {
        "_id": "5c7166f2591610007f6d44d6",
        "name": "E 220"
    },
    "serie": null
},
{
    "_id": "5c716c6a591610007f6d44f3",
    "model": {
        "_id": "5c7166fe591610007f6d44d8",
        "name": "C 180"
    },
    "serie": {
        "_id": "5c716ba4591610007f6d44e3",
        "name": "C-Class"
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5c716c6e591610007f6d44f4",
    "model": {
        "_id": "5c716702591610007f6d44d9",
        "name": "C 200"
    },
    "serie": {
        "_id": "5c716ba4591610007f6d44e3",
        "name": "C-Class"
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5c716c74591610007f6d44f5",
    "model": {
        "_id": "5c716705591610007f6d44da",
        "name": "C 220"
    },
    "serie": {
        "_id": "5c716ba4591610007f6d44e3",
        "name": "C-Class"
    }
}
```

I want to categorise each model name under their series.
**For example C-Class: ['E300', 'E220'] etc, and also put models with no series defined into an object NoClass.**

It's too much for an inline jsx (at least it seems so ??) so I need some helper functions, but I can't manage to do the manipulation because every time I get error that the data is undefined which means it tries to render code before it even appears there and gets modified.

So pretty much I want to filter data into new objects and then render these instead of the original props data. And I don't know how to do that all before rendering

My current attempt at doing it inline - it does render however it doesn't check for empty series objects and breaks when where are more than 1 different serie:

```
class ModelSelect extends React.Component {
render() {
    const { models } = this.props
    return (
        models && <div className={"ModelSelect_Wrapper"}>
            <Select placeholder={"Model"} loading={models.loading} disabled={models.data.length === 0}>
                {_.uniqBy(models.data, 'name').map((serie) =>
                    <OptGroup label={serie.serie.name}>
                        {!models.loading && models.data.map((model, index) =>
                            <Option value={model.model._id} key={index}>{model.model.name}</Option>
                        )}
                    </OptGroup>
                )}

            </Select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You can do your data manipulation right after const { models } = this.props line. Suppose your model is an array. Then, you can create new variable like const newData = models.length > 0 ? some logic : []. Then you can have your map based on newData. So if newData is empty it renders nothing but won't throw an error either.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using stores. You have several options available, such as `Redux`, `Flux`, and `Mobx`. Unfortunately, learning to use Stores is a bit hard. coming from angular, i would compare a store to `$scope` from angular.js 1x, with the difference being that there is no magic causing the view to rerender, you have to rely on react detecting a change in the props in order for rerender to occur. the idea is that the store is a data structure, and when it is modified, the components which are using the store as a prop will be rerendered. this works great especially if you are fetching data async.

the basic pattern would be

1. use `componentDidMount()` to load the data in Higher Order Component
2. transform the data and update the store with the new data
3. you are passing the store to your component like `<MyComponent store={store} />`
4. when data is loaded, you pass the store to the child component

doing it this way your component may look something like

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        store:{}
    }
    state = {
        loading: true
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.store.loadSomeData().then(()=>this.setState({loading:false}));
    }
    render(){
        return this.state.loading ? null : <MyChildComponent store={store} />
    }
}
```

please remember, you are responsible for loading and transforming the data in your store, and this is just a generalized overview of how your component show load and receive that transformed data. your exact approach will vary wildly based upon the store you are using.

My answer can't be any more specific than this, because there is far too much to cover, and the scope of the work required varies highly depending on the library you use. For example, mobx-3x all you do is decorate your component with `@inject` and `@observer` and it handles the `shouldComponentUpdate()` implementation for you.

So your, first step is to pick a store, and then go from there. best of luck.